# How to use Precision and Scalling while performing multiplcation and division of decimal number in DB2

Tags: casting, db2, decimal

I have a table data as below

```
+------+----------+---------------+
| col1 |   col2   |     col3      |
+------+----------+---------------+
|    1 | 32679050 | 1017593887.44 |
|    1 | 45756670 | 917011235.08  |
+------+----------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to multiply and divide the above table data as follows and reciving the error as **SQLCODE=-802, SQLSTATE=22003**

```
Select col1, decimal(sum(col2)*sum(col3),17,2) as col2, decimal(sum(col2)/sum(col3),17,2) as col3 from 
table group by col1;
```

As i have understood the problem is coming from the precesion and scalling of the output column and could understood how does the precision and scalling work in DB2.

Any valuable leads would be helpful!!

Comment: -802 is arithmetic overflow or underflow.  This is a FAQ. Cast to double/float before multiplication/division, and separately protect against division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1,decimal(sum(col2)*decimal(sum(col3),17,2),17,2) as col2, 
decimal(sum(col2)/decimal(sum(col3),17,2),17,2) as col3 from table group by col1;
```

The above SQL query solved the problem.

So, I have converted the sum of decimal values to decimal and converted the result to either multiplication or division of decimal values to decimal again to acheive my final result.

Comment: Do remember that in Db2, casting decimal values will truncate the values rather than round them. Consider using DECFLOAT data types function to avoid arithmetic overflow or underflows and the `QUANTIZE()` function to round and reduce precision when needed